# why my pipeline page always show this message "Build with confidence"?

Tags: gitlab

Even i have added the .gitlab-ci.yml file in my repo root directory but still when i click on Pipelines tab it shows this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot and found a solution. Yes I have found it, although it has to be run manually every time which is still an issue but i would like to share my solution here. REF# https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37816
just add /new at the end of web url e.g https://gitlab.com/group/your_project/pipelines/new
in my case it is like http://192.168.-.-:8000/root/test-project/pipelines/new
hope it helps.